# Blender three json export errors

Tags: json, three.js, blender

I installed the three.js plugin for blender to export models to json format, i test it with very simple model contains materials of colors without textures but i get errors if i choose materials in options as in attached image, when i do not choose materials option i can export it but get error in reading it with JSONLoader, the error is "can not read property length of undefined" in three.min.js:264

[the blender errors](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2F_KXzRsuI2bFdDUVJzcWVZcms/view?usp=sharing)
[the exported json file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2F_KXzRsuI2R0VlUTNtM3E5NWc/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't added your code here but I think your problem is that when you don't export the material from blender, you have to make your own material; then assign it in JSON loader. If you try to get the material from the JSON file it obviously is nonexistent.

I have faced this error many times. Mainly because I wasn't using the latest releases of three.js or the exporter. If you are using a tutorial check that too.